# What does locus of $\operatorname{arg}(z-i)=\pi/4$ on an Argand diagram?

Tags: complex-numbers, locus

By thinking of the question in terms of vectors, any point lying on the locus, would satisfy that the vector from $i$ to $z$ would make an angle of $\pi/4$ with the horizontal line, like this:

[image]

But converting the equation into Cartesian co-ordinates, I get $y=x+1$, which as you know looks like so:
[image]

But if the part of the curve with negative x-values is included, then the $\theta$ would no longer be $\pi/4$, as shown here:

[image]
So by choosing a $z$ such that Re($z$)$<0$, arg($z$)$\neq \pi/4$

So my question is, which graph is correct, pink or green? And where have I gone wrong

Comment: The pink line can be written in cartesian coordinates as $y = x+1$ restricted to $x > 0$ and would be correct since as you point out for $x \leq 0$ the argument condition is not satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

In general, $$\arg(\alpha+i\beta)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$ implies $$\frac{\beta}{\alpha}=\arctan(\frac{\pi}{4})=1\Rightarrow \alpha=\beta,\color{red}{\text{ and }\alpha,\beta\ge0}$$
Assume $z=x+iy$. Therefore, $$z-i=x+iy-i=x+i(y-1)$$ Then $\arg(z-i)=\pi/4$ means the real part is equal to the imaginary part, i.e. $x=y-1$ Hence, $$y=x+1,\color{red}{\text{ and }x\ge0,y-1\ge0\Rightarrow y\ge1}$$
is the locus.

Answer (score -1):

pink, as it is the way arg is usually presented. the negative values represent a different arg -(3pi/4)